# Search filter in flutter

Tags: android, dart, flutter

Searching is working but I have applied the search filter in `itemBuilder` whenever I search for something and it finds at position 5 for example than `itemBuilder` building view for those positions where items have not found.
I want the list of founded items or no record text single times.

```
Expanded(
    child: ListView.builder(
        itemCount: productList.length,
        itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
            return filter == null || filter == "" ? productItem(productList[index][DatabaseHelper.columnProductName], height, productList[index][DatabaseHelper.columnPrice] )
                : productList[index][DatabaseHelper.columnProductName].toLowerCase().contains(filter.toLowerCase())
                ? productItem(productList[index][DatabaseHelper.columnProductName], height, productList[index][DatabaseHelper.columnPrice] ) : new Container(child: Text('No record'),);
        },
    ),
),
```

My Controller

```
@override
void initState() {
    super.initState();

    _query();

    controller.addListener(() {
        setState(() {
            filter = controller.text;
        });
    });    
}
```

[image]

Comment: @pskink where should it be rebuilt.

Comment: @anmol.majhail I tried it but in that condition searching is not working

Comment: @pskink I'm  going to try this code thanks

Comment: @pskink my list type is ` List<Map<String, dynamic>> productList;`  and unable to use `contains`.